# How to find specific pattern in crawling a web page using "Beautiful Soup"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to get username of twitteres from [twitaholic](http://twitaholic.com/) website, I run following code but  my result printed None (without error message), what is wrong with it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.twitaholic.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.findall(id="@(.*)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make a mistake in using regex. You should compile the pattern then pass it to the `soup`.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.twitaholic.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'chrome'}
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup(text=re.compile("@(.*)")))
```